# Javascript / AJAX - get parameter array from form

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, forms

I've got this form, which generates an array as output, and I want to send that via AJAX to a PHP page.
The form is build up like this: [using a lot more entries]

```
 <input type="hidden" name="reisdata[Van]" value="'.$reisdata["Van"].'">
 <input type="hidden" name="reisdata[Naar]" value="'.$reisdata["Naar"].'">
```

and the php page needs to recieve the data as an array.

Now, someone showed me this piece of code, to pass an array in AJAX via POST, but I still don't know how to read the array in javascript.

So: **How can I read an array from a form, in AJAX / Javascript?**
***Do I just read it by typing: document.formname.reisdata ?***

This is my AJAX code:

```
// Algemene functie om een xmlHttp object te maken. Via dit object kunnen we later Ajax calls plaatsen

function GetXmlHttpObjectReisData() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try { // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e) { // Internet Explorer
        try { xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {
            try { xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
function CallAjaxReisDataFunction(serverScript,arguments)
{
    var xmlHttp = new GetXmlHttpObjectReisData(); // Functie welke wordt uitgevoerd als de call naar de server klaar is State 4)
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
        {
            handleReisDataResult(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    // Ajax call (Request naar de server met eventuele parameters (arguments))
    xmlHttp.open("POST", serverScript, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", arguments.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(arguments);
}

function callReisDataServer(serverScript,van,naar)
{
    CallAjaxReisDataFunction(serverScript,"?&reisdata=" + reisdata);
}

function handleReisDataResult(responseText)
{
    document.getElementById('reis').innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

This is the code someone ( @mephisto123 ) gave me before, but this works with a predefined javascript array:

```
var postdata = {"provincie":"123","reisdata":{"Overstap":"234","Van":"345"}};
var post = "";
var url = "data-reis-refresh.php";
var key, subkey;
for (key in postdata) {
    if (typeof(postdata[key]) == object) {
        foreach (subkey in postdata[key]) {
            if (post != "") post += "&";
            post += key + "%5B" + subkey + "%5D=" + postdata[key][subkey];
        }
    }
    else post += key + "=" + postdata[key];
}
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", post.length);
req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
req.send(post);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say you want to read the array from the **submitted** form in JavaScript.  The form is submitted to your server, no?  And you said that the server code is PHP.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is indeed a bit weird. I should have left the submitted part out. It should be: read the array from a form when the form is submitted (when I use: document.forms[formname].submit(); )

Comment: Well but why do you need "read the array" when you're submitting it?  All you need to do is build the parameters for the AJAX request, and the form field names apparently already are of the form that the server expects. (If not, then why is the form created with field names like that?)

Comment: Yes, That is indeed what I want to do. And I want to "read" the value because I need to send the array via Javascript / AJAX via POST to the PHP file. I'm not sure how to do this, so I ask for your advise :)
The reason I build an array is for the usage in the rest of my page. Also, I used to have everything in an auto refreshing iframe, but I'm not switching to a DIV combined with AJAX.

Comment: Also, I don't like to recommend JavaScript frameworks generally, but this particular case is one pretty good reason to consider something like Prototype, jQuery, or really any simple framework with AJAX support. There are some browser quirks that such libraries handle for you, and it really simplifies the process a lot. However, you can certainly do it all yourself if you prefer.

Comment: If this would be very easy when using JQuery, I'm all in for that. But, could you then explain to me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field names are generated with names like that, then there's nothing special to be done. Just gather up the form parameters, URL-encode the names and values, and POST to the server. (That process is not exactly trivial, because you need to be sensitive to the different types of form elements and the ways that their values are determined, but the complexity has nothing to do with what the field names look like.)

As a note on terminology, in JavaScript an Array instance is indexed numerically.  Using string property names is a capability of JavaScript objects in general, and one does not refer to such things as "arrays" if you don't want JavaScript programmers to be confused, or to give you pedantic instruction like this :-)

Again, though, in this case you've just got form fields with "funny" names, and JavaScript doesn't particularly care about that.

*edit* — Here's a quick attempt at a function to serialize all the elements in a form:

```
function serialize( form ) {
  var rv = [], el = null, opt = null;
  form = form || document.forms[0];

  function ffv( name, value ) {
    return encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; ++i) {
    var el = form.elements[i];
    switch (el.tagName) {
      case 'INPUT': {
        switch (el.type.toLowerCase()) {
          case 'checkbox':
          case 'radio':
            if (el.checked)
              rv.push( ffv(el.name, el.value) );
            break;
          case 'text':
          case 'password':
          case 'hidden':
            rv.push( ffv(el.name, el.value) );
            break;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 'SELECT': {
        opt = el.options[el.selectedIndex];
        rv.push( ffv(el.name, opt.value || opt.innerText) );
        break;
      }
      case 'TEXTAREA': {
        rv.push( ffv(el.name, el.value) );
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return rv.join('&');
}
```

Then you'd call the function when you call ".send()" on your XHR object:

```
req.send( serialize() );
```

The function as written will by default serialize the first form on the page. You can pass it a form explicitly if necessary.  It might have a couple of problems with old versions of IE, I guess; in particular I can't remember whether "innerText" always works for `<option>` elements.

What that function does is look at each form element, figure out its value (and whether it should be included in the submit at all), and then create a name/value pair of the form

> name=value

Both the name and the value are first encoded in that inner "ffv()" function, so that your fields will end up looking like

> reisdata%5BNaar%5D=something

The whole list of inputs is then joined together with "&" to create the overall parameter set to be passed to PHP (or any other server-side language for that matter).

If you wanted to try jQuery, then the whole thing would be tremendously easier.  There's a rich API for AJAX operations, but in your case it could be as simple as

```
$.post( url, $('form').serialize(), function( result ) { ... } );
```

Comment: So, you are saying Javascript can't handle associative arrays, but it will handle my associative array properly? Now that seems a bit weird to me?

ALso, could I then just use this in my code?
`var postdata document.formname.reisdata`

Comment: JavaScript objects can have string-named properties, but they're generally not called "associative arrays" (in JavaScript). The real point is that there's no need to even try to create a JavaScript object that mirrors the server-side associative array structure because the form (according to the HTML in your question) already has field names that reflect that.

Comment: Oh ok, that sounds very reasonable!
So using the code `var postdata document.formname.reisdata` would work? (where document.formname.reisdata would be the associative array / javascript object, instead of the manually entered array?)

Comment: No, that's not it.  Forget about the whole associative array issue (for a moment). When you're making an AJAX post like that, you have to turn the form fields into an encoded parameter string first. I'll see if I can find some description of the process on the web someplace.

Comment: I can't wait to understand this :)

Comment: OK, [this page here](http://ra-ajax.org/how-to-create-an-ajax-library-part-6-serializing-your-forms) isn't the prettiest or smartest code I've ever seen, but it's not bad.  That whole "serializeForm" function goes through a set of form elements and builds a parameter string. The main thing that it does **not** do that you will have to do is use "encodeURIComponent()" on your element names (the "el.name" variable in that code).

Comment: That page won't load here... (I get a Server Error page) But you mentioned it could also be done easily in JQuery, perhaps you could tell me more about that, it if really is that much easier?

Comment: I don't know why it won't load, but I just looked at the code more closely and it's broken anyway :-)  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I see you have included all kinds of data, though I'm only using hidden input fields, so I won't need all. But could you explain a bit about how it works? Because those variable names aren't very clear to me, aswell as what this script outputs... How would I use this in combination with a php page that I want to load, which recieves its data via POST?
Also, I"m not really sure if this is jQuery or Javascript? Because you mentioned jQuery was the way to go...

Comment: OK I'll add a brief description.

Comment: jQuery seems indeed amazingly much easier...
It might seem a bit stupid, but in the result function in jQuery, I would then simply use the jQuery.load() function, which replaces the html() of the DIV I want to place the content in?

Comment: To update content you'd use ".html()" - the ".load()" function is for just doing HTTP "GET" operations to fetch content.  The [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) is pretty good at explaining those things.

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks!
I had a quick look at your post() function and the html() function, and now understand that the post() function will call the content, and then I can place it in the html(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to all the readers:
In the end, I ended up using jQuery .post() and .get().
Those are extremely easy to use and a lot faster and more flexible.